# James T. Kirk: Why "Tiberius"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, names

Considering the relatively exotic nature of "[Tiberius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiberius)", is there a story behind [James T. Kirk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_T._Kirk)'s middle name? Do we perhaps know what the professions of his parents were?

Comment: **warning! tv tropes!** Because the name of a Roman emperor is a perfect one for a [Large Ham](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LargeHam)?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9815/1234

Comment: And in the first episode, his name was James R. Kirk.

Comment: This, of course, is wrong from the get-go - and you would know it you had been in the military. He is the captain of a starship. His first name is Captain,
his middle name is Kirk,
and his last name is Sir. (possibly spelled with an exclamation mark) Where do people get some silly ideas - Tiberius, really...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Tiberius was the first name of Kirk's [Grandfather](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tiberius_Kirk).

This is also true (as you'd expect as Nero's arrival comes after Tiberius Kirk was born) in the 'rebooted' universe, as it's explicitly referenced in dialogue in *Star Trek*:

> **George Kirk:** What are we gonna call him?
>
> **Winona Kirk:** We can name him after your father.
>
> **George Kirk:** Tiberius, you kiddin' me? No, that's the worst. Let's name him after your dad. Let's call him Jim.
>
> **Winona Kirk:** Jim. Okay, Jim it is.

Comment: Thank you. There's a [more detailed](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Tiberius_Kirk) entry on Memory Beta.

Answer (score 9):

It is mentioned in the novel of the film [Star Trek The Motion Picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture_%28novel%29).

> My name is James Tiberius Kirk. Kirk because my father and his male
>   forebears followed the old custom of passing along a family identity
>   name. I received James because it was both the name of my father’s
>   beloved brother as well as that of my mother’s first love instructor.
>   **Tiberius, as I am forever tired of explaining, was the Roman emperor
>   whose life for some unfathomable reason fascinated my grandfather
>   Samuel.**

It was because of his grandfather's interest in Roman Emperors.

Comment: "Love instructor???"

Answer (score 4):

Roddenberry must have liked the name. Just before Star Trek he produced The Lieutenant, a cold war drama set at Camp Pendleton. The title character, played by Gary Lockwood, was Lt. William T. Rice. The T stands for - you guessed it - Tiberius!

[image: The Lieutenant]

Comment: The OP was looking for an in-universe reason, not why the character was named thusly by the creators. For that question, you want to look at this; "[Why was the character of Captain Kirk given the middle name “Tiberius”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139981/why-was-the-character-of-captain-kirk-given-the-middle-name-tiberius)"